# Variable are not being set when it is declared in the class body

Tags: javascript, typescript

Why is the variable not defined when there is a declaration of it in the body of the class and when it is extended and called by the parent class?

```js
class Parent {
  constructor() {
    this.setVariable();
  }

  setVariable() {}
}

class Child extends Parent {
  variable; //if i remove, the output is 1 instead of undefined

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  setVariable() {
    this.variable = 1;
  }

  output() {
    return this.variable;
  }
}

let child = new Child();
console.log(child.output());
```

If I remove the `variable` declaration in the class body the output is **1** as you can see below

```js
class Parent {
  constructor() {
    this.setVariable();
  }

  setVariable() {}
}

class Child extends Parent {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  setVariable() {
    this.variable = 1;
  }

  output() {
    return this.variable;
  }
}

let child = new Child();
console.log(child.output());
```

But, I'm using **TypeScript**, so I need to declare the variable and its type in the class body and declaring the output is `undefined`, if I don't declare the error is the following:

```
Property 'variable' does not exist on type 'Child'.ts(2339)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class fields run immediately after `super` calls.

When no value is assigned in a class field, but the class field is declared, it's the same as assigning `undefined` in it.

So, this:

```
class Child extends Parent {
  variable; //if i remove, the output is 0 instead of undefined

  constructor() {
    super();
  }
```

is syntax sugar for

```
class Child extends Parent {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.variable = undefined;
  }
```

which means that the `setVariable` call called in the super constructor has the `this.variable` overwritten.

Give the `variable` a type, to indicate to TypeScript that it's for documenting the type (ignored in emitted code), rather than a class field (included in emitted code), and it'll work as desired:

```
class Child extends Parent {
  variable: number | undefined;

  // etc
```

which transpiles to just

```
class Child extends Parent {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
```

(you could even omit the child constructor entirely if you wanted)

[TS Demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKYCcCmA7ALtA3gWAFDWmAHsUI0EBXYNIhACgEos8CC0ALASwgDoIk0ANUScwAIxBJGAbhbQAvnjn8hI8ZMZZFubXlCQYAYS4gAJtCQAPNKlMx4ydM3zQAbmolIAXNBQUAtmJICNAAPtAUKKZIAGacKEimsi4qwgiinpo4LmxcvO7p6kjQALzQAIzJBNoERBRoAA71WXIEyGgUCCjQHNw8BRmSVQp4uriSGMAm5mUJAO7QxpxmMnokEESSPCBEAOZ0U8umPHWNzQwM0kA)

Transpiled JavaScript code demo here:

```js
"use strict";
class Parent {
    constructor() {
        this.setVariable();
    }
    setVariable() { }
}
class Child extends Parent {
    setVariable() {
        this.variable = 1;
    }
    output() {
        return this.variable;
    }
}
let child = new Child();
console.log(child.output());
```

Comment: I did what you said, but it keeps returning `undefined`, went to see the source code for the page (I'm using Next.JS). It seems that Babel transpiles:

`(0,node_modules_next_node_modules_babel_runtime_helpers_esm_defineProperty__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__.default)((0,node_modules_next_node_modules_babel_runtime_helpers_esm_assertThisInitialized__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.default)(_this), "variable", void 0);`

Comment: You have modules interfering with the code. Try putting it all into one file for readability. Go to the TypeScript demo link in the answer - you can see the compiled code without modules for yourself, it appears to be what you're looking for.

Comment: Got it, so it would be a bug in Babel of Next.JS